# how to get the nth numeric field in a string using grep?

Tags: bash, grep

How to get the second numeric field using grep?
For example, there is a string 12 34 56 78 and I would like to get the third number, which I can separate the string into different tokens:

```
echo "ab12 34_56.78" | grep -Eo "[[:digit:]]+"
```

The out put is

```
12 
34
56
78
```

How to choose the nth number from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of bash possibilities, assuming you did `N=3` (or whichever field you want).

```
echo "ab12 34_56.78" | grep -Eo "[[:digit:]]+" | tail -n+$n | head -n1
echo "ab12 34_56.78" | grep -Eo "[[:digit:]]+" | tr '\n' '\t' | cut -f$N
```

You can easily do this in awk, without additional shell commands:

```
echo "ab12 34_56.78" | awk -vN=3 -F'[^[:digit:]]+' '{print $(N+($1==""))}'
```

`-F` sets the field separator to a regular expression which matches any sequence of non-digits; adding `($1=="")` to `N` is to deal with the possibility that there is no non-digit before the first number.

If you have Gnu grep or some other grep implementation which offers PCRE, you could use the `\K` "match point reset" assertion:

```
echo "ab12 34_56.78" | grep -Po '(?:[[:digit:]]+[^[:digit:]]+){2}\K[[:digit:]]+'
```

or if you want to use `$N` to control the number of the match:

```
echo "ab12 34_56.78" | grep -Po '(?:[[:digit:]]+[^[:digit:]]+){'$((N-1))'}\K[[:digit:]]+'
```

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
echo "ab12 34_56.78" | grep -Eo "[[:digit:]]+" | sed -n 3p
```

or

```
echo "ab12 34_56.78" | sed -E 's/^([^[:digit:]]*[[:digit:]]+){2}[^[:digit:]]+([[:digit:]]+).*/\2/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sed

```
:>echo "ab12 34_56.78" | sed 's/[^0-9]/\n/g' |  grep -v '^$'
12
34
56
78
:>

[^0-9] --> Any digit other than numbers 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9  
\n --> New line char    
^ -- > start of line   
$ --> End of line
```

Replaced any char except number with **New line** character and then removed blank line.